# Content stealing in wordpress: Redirection if browser has javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect

i have some serious problems with content stealers, stealing my content and publishing it on their sites with ads. So i installed a content protection plugin, but with javascript disabled, the stealer has also the opportunity to steal my content.

I found that little peace of code, but it does not prevent the pageload, only showing a message, so that the stealer also can use **crtl+u** to view the source code:

```
    <div id="noscript" 
         style="position:fixed;
                z-index:999999;
                text-align:center;
                padding:150px;" >
    <h2>Enable JavaScript!</h2>
    <p>Sorry for the inconvenience but you must enable JavaScript in your 
       Browser to visit this site!</p>
    <p>&mdash; The Team</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('noscript').style.display="none";
    </script>
```

Did anyone have a little php code in mind, to make a redirection to a html site if javascript is not enabled. thank you.

Comment: Those copying your content can still use a headless browser which can interpret javascript and make a copy bypassing your protections. Reliable crawling-protection is extremely hard.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=noscript.html">
</noscript>
```

Comment: thx, yes i tried it, but this has no effect on browser extensions like umatrix

Comment: The problem here is with client browser not on your code